# What's causing this tunnel effect to render incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, graphics, html5-canvas, 2d

I'm currently attempting to create a sort of 3D tunnel effect in Javascript using the canvas tag.

It works, in the sense that it actually renders something, but it looks like this:

[image]

Not only is that not a tunnel, but it also takes up only a quarter of the canvas for some reason.

I wish I knew how to solve this, but I'm not getting any errors from the console, and the script itself seems to be running just fine, so I don't know where to start.

```
var texWidth = 256;
var texHeight = 256;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var texture = new Array(texHeight);
var distanceTable = new Array(h);
var angleTable = new Array(h);

var imageData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
var w = imageData.width;
var h = imageData.height;

for (i = 0; i < texHeight; i++) {
    texture[i] = new Array(texWidth);
}

for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
    distanceTable[j] = new Array(w);
    angleTable[j] = new Array(w);
}

for (y = 0; y < texHeight; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < texHeight; x++) {
        texture[y][x] = x ^ y;
    }
}

for (y2 = 0; y2 < h; y2++) {
    for (x2 = 0; x2 < w; x2++) {
        let angle;
        let distance;
    
        let ratio = 32.0;
        distance = ~~(ratio * texHeight / Math.sqrt((x2 - w / 2.0) * (x2 - w / 2.0) + (y2 - h / 2.0) * (y2 - h / 2.0))) % texHeight;
        angle = Math.abs(~~(0.5 * texWidth * Math.atan2(y2 - h / 2.0, x2 - w / 2.0) / Math.PI));
        
        distanceTable[y2][x2] = distance;
        angleTable[y2][x2] = angle;
    }
}

var animation = 0;

function draw() {
    animation = animation + 0.01;
  
    let shiftX = texWidth * 1.0 * animation;
    let shiftY = texHeight * 0.25 * animation;
    
    for (y3 = 0; y3 < h; y3++) {
        for (x3 = 0; x3 < w; x3++) {
            let id = y3 * w + x3 * 4;
            let c = texture[~~(distanceTable[y3][x3] + shiftX) % texWidth][~~(angleTable[y3][x3] + shiftY) % texHeight];
            
            imageData.data[id] = 0;
            imageData.data[id+1] = 0;
            imageData.data[id+2] = c;
            imageData.data[id+3] = 255;
        }
    }
        
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Since I have very little else to work with, I tried modifying some of the variables. That produces some interesting strobe-like effects, but not much else.

Comment: Please use `let` in all loop blocks to avoid global variables: `for (i = 0; i < texHeight; i++) {` should be `for (let i = 0; i < texHeight; i++) {`. It's common to declare arrays like `[]` rather than `new Array()`. If you don't know where to start debugging, check out [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `y3 * w + x3 * 4` is the same as `(y3 * w) + (x3 * 4)`, what you need is `(y3 * w + x3) * 4`.

Comment: Changing that equation seems to have fixed it. I'll keep this in mind next time I work with ImageData.